# SKSpriteNode button stuck (iOS) after letting go. Advice needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

So... I am working on this small Mario-like game for iOS and have run into a problem that I cannot seem to fix.

When using my controls (see the screenshot) they sometime get "stuck" as in, the iOS device did not notice that I let go of a button. This causes the player to keep on moving in a direction after you have let go of the button.

Edit: It seems that the malfunction happens when I click two buttons at the exact same time.

Hopefully, someone will be able to spot what I can do differently in the following code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        [self touchStateChanged:touchLocation buttonState:YES];
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint prevTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
        [self touchStateChanged:prevTouchLocation buttonState:NO];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        [self touchStateChanged:touchLocation buttonState:YES];
    }   
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        // Some other logic... {...}

        [self touchStateChanged:touchLocation buttonState:NO];
    }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        [self touchStateChanged:touchLocation buttonState:NO];
    }
}

-(void)touchStateChanged:(CGPoint)location buttonState:(BOOL)state
{
    SKNode *n = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([n.name isEqualToString:@"LeftMove"]) {
        self.player.moveLeft = state;
    }

    else if ([n.name isEqualToString:@"RightMove"]) {
        self.player.moveRight = state;
    }
    else if ([n.name isEqualToString:@"Jump"]) {
        self.player.didJump = state;
    }  
}
```

Screenshot showing buttons: [image]

Thanks :-)

---

*Partly Solved...*

### Current solution:

Added an instance variable called `_touchEvent` of type `UIEvent` and added the following line to `touchesEnded`:

```
_touchEvent = event;
```

Added the following code to my `update` method:

```
if (_touchEvent && (int)[[_touchEvent allTouches]count] == 0) {
    self.player.moveLeft = NO;
    self.player.moveRight = NO;
    self.player.didJump = NO;
}

if (_touchEvent && (int)[[_touchEvent allTouches]count] == 1) {
    for (UITouch *touch in [_touchEvent allTouches]) {
        SKNode *n = [self nodeAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];
        if ([n.name isEqualToString:@"Jump"]) {
            self.player.moveLeft = NO;
            self.player.moveRight = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code here not in an external website (links may break). If it's too much code to paste here you should narrow it down anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I will remember that for some other time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the location of touch (in `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method) is outside any node.

Try to implement something like this

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (SKNode *node in yourButtonsArray) {
        // Some other logic... {...}

        [node setState:NO];
    }
}
```

Or you should take a look at KKButtonBehaviour from KoboldKit framework.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly, there will be a new malfunction taking place. Now, if you 1) jump and move left at once, and 2) let go of jump, it would automatically stop moving left as well even though you might still be holding down the "move left"-button. Thanks, though :-)!

Comment: @MFaarkrog Yeah, my suggestion is a little bit unperfect. In case of the maximum number of touches at one time can be more than one, add node you press in some array when the `touchesBegan`, and when `touchesEnded` check the nodes are still "pressed" and set `state:NO` to those which not pressed.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a somewhat modified version of your idea. I saved the UIEvent from clicks in an instance variable and then used it in my update method. This way I can check if any buttons are actually pressed.